# Incompatibility between Dotnet core, JSNLog and Serilog

Tags: serilog, jsnlog, .net-core

I try to use JSNLog in structured mode with Serilog as explained in the documentation: 
http://jsnlog.com/Documentation/HowTo/StructuredLogging

I have the following code in the startup.cs

```
var jsnlogConfiguration = new JsnlogConfiguration 
{
serverSideMessageFormat = "[UserIp: %userHostAddress], [Url: %url], [Browser: %userAgent] %message"
};

app.UseApplicationInsightsRequestTelemetry()
    .UseApplicationInsightsExceptionTelemetry()
    .UseStaticFiles()
    .UseMvc(routes => { routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"); })
    .UseJSNLog(new LoggingAdapter(loggerFactory), jsnlogConfiguration); // Javascript logging
```

And in my project.json, I have the following configuration:

```
"JSNLog.AspNetCore": "2.20.1",
    "Serilog": "2.3.0",
    "Serilog.Extensions.Logging": "1.2.0",
    "Serilog.Sinks.File": "3.1.0",
    "Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile": "3.1.0",
    "Serilog.Sinks.Literate": "2.0.0",
    "Serilog.Sinks.AzureTableStorage": "2.0.0",
    "Serilog.Settings.Configuration": "2.1.0",
    "Serilog.Enrichers.Environment": "2.1.0",
    "Serilog.Enrichers.Thread": "2.0.0"
```

When I try to add 
"JSNLog.Serilog": "2.20.1" in the project.json file, I receive the following errors at compile time:

> The type or namespace name 'LoggingAdapter' could not be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest versions of JSNLog now work well with .Net Core. Have a look at:
http://jsnlog.com/Documentation/DownloadInstall/ForAspNetCore
https://github.com/mperdeck/jsnlog.AspNet5Demo

I am the author of JSNLog.